# Android Firebase create lists based on group membership

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a list that only contains items of a particular group. For example, I've created/written a "fruits" node and a "groups" node myself in the database console (including the groups' keys).

Relatively new to Firebase, so still trying to wrap my ahead around flattening data structures.

The JSON (showing "fruits" and "groups") looks like the following:

```
 {
  "fruits" : {
    "apple" : {
      "color" : "appleColorValueHere",
      "groups" : {
        "GroupABCKey" : true,
        "GroupXYZKey" : true
      },
      "origin" : "appleOriginValueHere",
      "size" : "appleSizeValueHere"
    },
    "orange" : {
      "color" : "orangeColorValueHere",
      "groups" : {
        "GroupABCKey" : true,
        "GroupXYZ" : true
      },
      "origin" : "orangeOriginValueHere",
      "size" : "orangeSizeValueHere"
    },
    "strawberry" : {
      "color" : "strawberryColorValueHere",
      "groups" : {
        "GroupJKLKey" : true
      },
      "origin" : "strawberryOriginValueHere",
      "size" : "strawberrySizeValueHere"
    }
  },
  "groups" : {
    "GroupABCKey" : {
      "members" : {
        "apple" : true,
        "orange" : true
      },
      "name" : "Group ABC Name Here"
    },
    "GroupJKLKey" : {
      "members" : {
        "strawberry" : true
      },
      "name" : "Group JKL Name Here"
    },
    "GroupXYZKey" : {
      "members" : {
        "apple" : true,
        "orange" : true
      },
      "name" : "Group XYZ Name Here"
    }
  }    ...
        ...
}
```

Within the app itself, a user can create a list which copies the entire `fruits` node into their newly created list (see JSON further down for `user-list-items`). I'm then displaying the items using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

Here is the code for how I'm doing that:

```
private void writeNewFruitList(String userId, String username, String email, String title) {
    final String key = databaseReference.child("fruit-lists").push().getKey();
    UserLists userLists = new UserLists(userId, username, email, title);

    HashMap<String, Object> updatedListToAddMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> itemToAdd =
            (HashMap<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().convertValue(userLists, Map.class);
    updatedListToAddMap.put("/fruit-lists/" + key, itemToAdd);
    updatedListToAddMap.put("/user-fruit-lists/" + userId + "/" + key, itemToAdd);

    databaseReference.updateChildren(updatedListToAddMap);

    final DatabaseReference subDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    subDatabaseReference.child("fruits").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, child.getKey());
                Log.d("fruitValues::", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                final String fruitKey= child.getKey();
                FruitModel fruitModel = child.getValue(FruitModel.class);

                Map<String, Object> nodeValues = fruitModel.toMap();
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                String new_path = "/user-list-items/" + key + "/" + fruitKey+ "/";
                childUpdates.put(new_path, nodeValues);
                subDatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

**Q:** How can I implement this process using groups? E.g., a user creates a list and only wants the newly created list to contain fruits that are of `GroupABCKey` but they also want the details of those fruits (size, origin etc).

Q2: What's the best way to edit my `FruitModel.java` to account for the groups?

```
public class FruitModel {
    public String size;
    public String origin;
    public String color;

    public FruitModel() {
    }

    public FruitModel(String size, String origin, String color) {
        this.size = size;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

        result.put("size", size);
        result.put("origin", origin);
        result.put("color", color);

        return result;
    }
    // getters & setters
}
```

Finally, here's what I believe the `user-list-items` node **would** look like if done correctly?

**listKey1forUserA** is what I am creating correctly (except for mapping the groups as mentioned previously).

**listKey2forUserA** is what I'm trying to accomplish - A user wants to create and populate a list only with items that are in "GroupJKLKey"

```
  "user-list-items" : {
    "listKey1forUserA" : {
      "apple" : {
        "color" : "appleColorValueHere",
        "groups" : {
          "GroupABCKey" : true,
          "GroupXYZ" : true
        },
        "origin" : "appleOriginValueHere",
        "size" : "appleSizeValueHere"
      },
      "orange" : {
        "color" : "orangeColorValueHere",
        "groups" : {
          "GroupABCKey" : true,
          "GroupXYZKey" : true
        },
        "origin" : "orangeOriginValueHere",
        "size" : "orangeSizeValueHere"
      },
      "strawberry" : {
        "color" : "strawberryColorValueHere",
        "groups" : {
          "GroupJKLKey" : true
        },
        "origin" : "strawberryOriginValueHere",
        "size" : "strawberrySizeValueHere"
      }
    },
    "listKey2forUserA" : {
      "strawberry" : {
        "color" : "strawberryColorValueHere",
        "groups" : {
          "GroupJKLKey" : true
        },
        "origin" : "strawberryOriginValueHere",
        "size" : "strawberrySizeValueHere"
      }
    }
  }
```

Is this the proper way to go about this? Any help or a point in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my usage has slightly changed since I originally posted this question, the two use cases below are still applicable with some minor adjusting. There's probably a better way to go about this, so I'd definitely welcome any suggestions or ideas from others.

The tl;dr is that you structure your database in such a way that you have a `groups` path and a `users` path. The `users` path contains **no** reference to groups. Get a datasnapshot of the children of a particular group (just need the keys) and add them to an ArrayList. > For each item in your ArrayList, plug that into the `users` path.

This will then allow access to the details of those users (or fruits, as used in my original question) and the ability to display that information or create new information however you see fit.

***Create/Write a list*** of people based on group membership:

```
private void writeListFromGroupMembership(){

    final DatabaseReference mainPathReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    final ArrayList<String> groupMembers = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference groupsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("groups")
            .child("someOtherChildYouMayHave")
            .child("nameOfGroupYouAreInterestedIn");

    /* Step 1: Get a list of people in a specific group that you are interested in */
    groupsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String groupMemberKey = child.getKey();

                if (child.getValue(Boolean.class) != null) {
                    groupMembers.add(groupMemberKey);
                } else {
                    // TODO
                }
            }

            /* Step 2: Loop through your list of people and insert them as a child like the following: */
            for (int i = 0; i < groupMembers.size(); i++) {
                final String singleGroupMember = groupMembers.get(i);

                mainPathReference.child("all-groups").child("anotherChildYouMayHave").child(singleGroupMember)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                // Make a POJO for the item and immediately turn it into a HashMap
                                Person person= dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                                Map<String, Object> nodeValues = person.toMap();

                                // Make a map for the items you are adding
                                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                                // The path where the items will be copied/written to.
                                String newPath = "/master-list-items/" + listKey + "/" + singleGroupMember + "/";

                                // Add the items to the update map
                                childUpdates.put(newPath, nodeValues);

                                // Do the update
                                mainPathReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: ", databaseError.toException());
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

    // your other onCancelled override method here

}
```

***Display a list*** of people based on group membership (using a Spinner, for example) :

```
public List<Person> persons;
...
private void getGroupMembers(String groupSelected) {
    groupRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("someOtherChildThatYouHouseGroupsUnder")
            .child(groupSelected)
            .child("members");

    groupRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String groupMember= child.getKey();

                selectedGroupMembers.add(groupMember);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedGroupMembers.size(); i++) {
                String singleMember = selectedGroupMembers.get(i);

                singleMemberDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("all-people")
                        .child(singleMember);

                singleMemberDatabaseReference .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Person person = dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                        persons.add(person);

                        personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(getApplicationContext(), persons);

                        recyclerView.setAdapter(personAdapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG,"onCancelled: ", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: ", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

For displaying a list of people based on group membership, my database structure is similar to:

```
{
   "all-groups":{
      "groupNameorKeyOfGroupName":{
         "details":{
            "meetingLocation":"110 William Street",
            "someOtherChild":"Your value"
         },
         "members":{
            "fakeUserA":true,
            "fakeUserB":true,
            "fakeUserC":true,
            "fakeUserD":true
         }
      }
   }
   "all-users":{
     "fakeUserA":{

     }, 
     "fakeUserB":{

     }
   }
}
```